# RoseDB error on trying to run .pl script

Tags: perl, rose-db-object

when I try to run this .pl script:

```
\#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use abc::abcBill;
use abc::abcBill::Manager;

abc::abcBill::Manager->update_abcBill(
 set => {  mb_status=>'Purged' },
 where=>[  mb_created_date => { ls => '2012-05-01 00:00:00' } ],
 debug =>1
);
```

The error I get is:

**Can't locate object method "update_abcBill" via package "abc::abcBill::Manager"**

I have checked my  `abcBill::Manager`, and I have a `make_manager` method there, but it just wont compile the .pl script.

Comment: It says that it cannot find the `update_abcBill` method. There's no mention of a `make_manager` method. Also, you might want to add `use warnings` to that script for good measure as it tells you about subtle mistakes.

Comment: Another thing: you are calling a class method that seems to do stuff to an object. Where is that object? You didn't create one already. Maybe there's something wrong with your logic.

Comment: We'd have to see abc::abcBill::Manager.

Comment: @simbabque: that's quite alright. The Rose::DB "Manager" class for a particular type is the thing that does stuff on a table. That update call is supposed to be mapped to an SQL call like `UPDATE abcBill SET mb_status = 'Purged' WHERE mb_created_date < '...'`. Why it doesn't work depends on how the `make_manager` method is actually called. If it's something like `__PACKAGE__->make_manager_methods('abcBill');` then `update_abcBill` should work being called on the package. @Schwern is right, we need to see `abc::abcBill::Manager` (and/or `abc::abcBill`).

Comment: package abc::abcBill::Manager;

use strict;

use base qw(Rose::DB::Object::Manager);

use abc::abcBill;

sub object_class { 'abc::abcBill' }

__PACKAGE__->make_manager_methods('abcBill');

Comment: thats how i defined my Manger for abcBill